# Magento 2: Display manufacturer on product view

Tags: magento2, product-view

I have my custom "sidebar_brand.phtml" in "catalog_product_view.xml".

```
<container name="right.product.container" as="rightProductContainer" label="Right Product Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-md-3 text-sm-center" >
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.info.sidebarbrands" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/sidebar-brand.phtml" after="product.info.main"/>
</container>
```

I have tried many different ways but I can not find out how to display the manufacturer attribute in this file.

Should I do it from the XML file or the phtml file?

I have seen different solutions, but nothing works. I am using Magento 2.2.3, how do I get the '$_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer');' working?

Sources:
https://www.dckap.com/blog/display-custom-attribute-value-product-viewlist-page-magento-2/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37305107/how-do-i-display-an-attribute-on-product-view-page-in-magento-2

I am failing all the time! Can someone please show me how it should be in my Magento version?

The phtml file sidebar_brand.phtml works fine, but I am not able to show the product attribute.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you update your whole xml code and also the sidebar_brand.phtml codes?

Comment: After testing everything I now found out that the attribute Manufacturer was not active as default in the attribute set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your layout changes seem to fine ( and expecting .phtml changes fine too ) then only possible issue could be enabling storefrontend settings to view on catalog pages.

you need to check attribute front-end setting :

> Stores->Attributes->Product

and find your `manufacturer` attribute ( click to edit ) and go to "**Storefront Properties**" ( as attached ) there you should change 
**Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront** to **Yes**

[image]

hopefully it will work.

Comment: Hello, it was more simple then this. After testing everything I now found out that the attribute Manufacturer was not active as default in the attribute set.

Might been working with Magento 1 too much!

Thank you for your help.